# Compare current depth with older depth

Tags: three.js

We have a scene rendered to a `WebGLRenderTarget` with a depth texture which is being passed to a `ShaderMaterial` in a different scene as `tDepth`. Following is the fragment shader for that `ShaderMaterial`. It does a depth check and then renders onto the canvas. (I can just disable autoclear of depth and have it working, but I want a custom depth function, hence the code).

```
varying vec2 vUv; 
uniform sampler2D tDepth;
uniform float width;
uniform float height;

void main() {
    vec2 clipCoord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x / width , gl_FragCoord.y / height)
    float oldDepth = texture2D(tDepth, clipCoord).r; // Gets wrong value.
    float currentDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
    if (oldDepth > currentDepth) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,0);
    } else {
        discard;
    }
}
```

How do I get the correct value of `oldDepth`?

Comment: how are you obtaining the `tDepth` texture? what format is it in?

Comment: @pailhead `tDepth` is the `renderTarget.depthTexture` passed as a uniform to the shader.

Comment: but what kind of data is inside of it? is it float?